# unzip a large multipart (spanned) gzip file on AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip

I have a huge csv file (about 60Gb), which is zipped and is stored as a multipart (spanned) gzip file on a s3 bucket. The individual files are like:

`file.csv.gz`
`file.csv1.gz`
`file.csv2.gz`
`file.csv3.gz`
....
`file.csv15.gz`

Each file has a size of 512Mb. I need to unzip them into a single csv file.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`cat file.csv.gz file.csv1.gz ... file.csv15.gz | gzip -dc > file.csv`

Note that you can't use `file.csv*.gz`, because the order will not be what you want, for example putting `file.csv10.gz` before `file.csv2.gz`. If you renamed them to `file.csv00.gz`, `file.csv01.gz`, etc., then you could just:

`cat file.csv*.gz | gzip -dc > file.csv`

Comment: Thanks Mark. That would be a great answer if I wanted to do it locally. But since the file parts are on S3 this cannot be done.